# How can I run eslint --fix on my JavaScript in Intellij-IDEA, Webstorm, other JetBrains IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea, eslint

When I save a file, I would like to run eslint, and have it fix any issues that eslint can fix.

I know this can be accomplished using the command line by running applying the `--fix` argument.

I also know that Intellij-IDEA has integration with Eslint directly; however, Intellij-IDEA uses stdin for it's integration which means you can't pass `--fix` as an argument.

Comment: I could not find anything on the Web telling me how to do this so I thought I'd ask/answer to help the next guy. I'd also add that Intellij IDEA should integrate this by default :)

Answer (score 14):

With a few quick steps you can setup a file watcher that will run eslint --fix on the files you save.

**Step by step:**

- Install the [File Watcher plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7177?pr=idea)
- Navigate to `Preferences > Tools > File Watchers` and create a new File Watcher
- Choose `File type: JavaScript`
- Optionally, apply a scope for the watcher. For example, I chose `$ProjectFileDir$/apps/web/src/` and included all of it's contents recursively.
- Choose the program to run. With node, npm, and eslint installed point to the eslint bin. In my project, the path was `$ProjectFileDir$/apps/web/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js`
- Apply the following arguments to run eslint with the fix option on the file that was saved `--fix $FileName$`
- Specify the working directory as `$FileDir$`.

Name, and save the File Watcher. Then, edit a JavaScript file in the directory you scoped and watch many of your errors and warnings go away! Thanks Eslint!

Note: If you find Intellij-IDEA asking if you want to load file changes without you saving know (which gets annoying) it's because the IDE is saving in the background. You can uncheck `Immediate file synchronization` to have a better editing experience.

[image]

Comment: This *almost* worked for me. When I tried it, webstorm couldn't find my node interpreter, maybe because I'm using nvm?. I just went into the 'Environment variables' menu and set PATH to be the location of my node executable, which for me was `~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/node`. You can find yours with `which node`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did just do one alteration put "scope" on "current file", cause that's what you want to, watch a file and fix it on save.

Answer (score 11):

Things have changed. You won't need external plugins. There is now native support for ESlint:

### Old (Deprecated):

ESlint Plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7494-eslint/

> As of Intellij 14, a plugin based on this one was bundled into the IDE release by Jetbrains. What's the diffrence? This plugin supports Intellij 13 and other versions, --fix option, quick fixes and other minor differences. Please make sure you are referring to this one before opening an issue.
>
> source: https://github.com/idok/eslint-plugin

---

### New (Native support)

[image]

### 1. "Automatic ESLint configuration"

The "Automatic ESLint configuration" option works fine for me, too. The IDE scans for `package.json` files with `eslint` dependencies and run it. (You could use different ESLint versions in one project).

ESLint config is auto detected from the nearest `.eslintrc.x` (e.g. `.json`) config file, or read from the `package.json`

> By default, PhpStorm uses the ESLint package from the project `node_modules` folder and the `.eslintrc.*` configuration file from the folder where the current file is stored. If no `.eslintrc.*` is found in the current file folder, PhpStorm will look for one in its parent folders up to the project root.

> If you have several `package.json` files with ESLint listed as a dependency, PhpStorm starts a separate process for each `package.json` and processes everything below it. This lets you apply a specific ESLint version or a specific set of plugins to each path in a monorepo or a project with multiple ESLint configurations.

### 2. Manual ESLint configuration

You can also set the Node interpreter + ESLint package + `.eslintrc` config manually

---

### Apply ESLint Code Style Rules

You can auto-import ***some*** code style rules from your ESLint config:

1. Inside your `.eslintrc` config file **context menu**
2. Select "*Apply ESLint Code Style Rules*"

   [image]
3. Check output in "*Event Log*" panel

---

### Configure Inspections

1. From "Warnings" tooltip select "Configure Inspections..."

   [image]
2. Activate "ESLint" under "Code quality tools"

   [image]
3. The "Problems" panel now lists ESLint issues AND (default) IDE problems

   [image]

You might want to disable IDEs default rules by and replace them with adequate ESLint rules. Otherwise you might see 2 problems for the same issue in the list.

---

### View Inspection Results

1. "Code" > "Run Inspection by Name..." > type "eslint"
2. You can "auto fix" problems, or fix the entire file (if rule can be fixed automatically)
3. Fixed problems are highlighted

   [image]

---

### Run/Debug Configuration [optional]

Alternative, you can set up a NPM script run configuration:

1. After ESLint installation, add a script section to `package.json`

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "eslint": "eslint"
   }
   ```
2. In "npm" panel, you should see the "eslint" script from your `package.json`.
3. You can edit its settings to e.g. run ESLint for current file only:

   [image]
4. Now you can run the NPM script:

   [image]

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.2/eslint.html?utm_campaign=PS&utm_medium=link&utm_source=product&utm_content=2020.2#ws_js_eslint_activate

Answer (score 1):

You better use the original third-party [ESLint plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7494), it does support quick fixes. See [project README](https://github.com/idok/eslint-plugin/blob/master/README.md) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Save Actions Plugin](https://github.com/dubreuia/intellij-plugin-save-actions)

> ### Installation
>
> #### IDE (recommended) Install it from your IDE (Intellij IDEA, PyCharm, etc.):
>
> "File > Settings > Plugins > Browse repositories... > Search 'Save
> Actions' > Category 'Code tools'"
>
> #### JetBrains plugin repository All versions of the plugin are available from the JetBrains plugin repository. You can download the
>
> jar and add it to your IDE (you won't get updates thought):
>
> "File > Settings > Plugins > Install plugin from disk..."

One of the options is "***Reformat file***" -> *Enable / disable formatting (configured in "File > Settings > Code Style"). See "Reformat only changed code" for more options*

Answer (score 0):

in my case is my project was created by vue-cli

add this line to your package.json

```
"lintfix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.vue src test/unit test/e2e/specs",
```

here are 3 ways you can do

1. Click on the green arrow on the left side
   [image]
2. Click on run button as the image below
   [image]
3. In terminal run: `npm run lintfix`

that all.