# WebStorm 2016.3.3 reformat code in Standard Style

Tags: coding-style, webstorm

Is there any way to automatically reformat code according to [StandardJS](http://standardjs.com/) requirements?

I've changed code style  in settings in WebStorm using this [Doc](https://github.com/feross/standard/blob/master/docs/webstorm.md). But I wanted the WebStorm not only to highlight errors, but also to reformat automatically (<kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> in Ubuntu) like after using  `standard --fix`.

Comment: Perhaps try [2017.1 EAP build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP) -- this [WEB-17331 ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17331) is might be what you are after (sorry, not a JavaScript person myself so cannot confirm this for sure)

Answer (score 0):

This feature is available in [2017.1 EAP](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP) - see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/webstorm-2017-1-eap-171-2272/

Comment: actually this was allready  in comments earlier, but as I've asked, was that possible to do something like that in current stable version. As an alternative I did something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883634/how-can-i-run-eslint-fix-on-my-javascript-in-intellij-idea-webstorm-other-je), until Webstorm 2017 final release. Anyway thank's for your reply.

Comment: Possible with JSCS (https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/08/maintaining-consistent-code-style/) and ESLint (https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/09/webstorm-2016-3-eap-163-3983/) - when these linters are used, you can auto-fix formatting issues by running the corresponding actions. For JSCS, you can import code style and use it for `Ctrl + Alt + L`. For ESLint, you can only fix code style errors using the corresponding action. Anyway, it's still better that using file watchers.